# Download PDF opened in new Window using Selenium JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, download

There are many questions which are similar to this has been asked in Stackoverflow. But this is something different
I am now currently automating an web application in which at the end of the application, PDF will be generated (Which will be displayed as a link, on clicking it PDF will open in a new window).
I am now currently using AUTOIT to automate Save AS dialog box. Is there any other way to download without using AutoIT.

I tried fetching the PDF URL from the link in the application under  tag, but it is actually invoking a JS to open a PDF in new Window
In new window PDF is actually in Embed tag in which src is about::blank
I fetched PDF complete src but when I used that URL without clearing any cookies, I am unable to get the PDF

Is there any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: do you or your organization have any problem with Autoit, because as per I know the dialog which shows on a browser to download is windows and chrome-based hence for non-browser elements Autoit is best, using Selenium Webdriver we cannot automate it....

Comment: Acutally while using AutoIT, the mouse needs to be fixed. i.e, if I accidentally moves my mouse during AutoIT execution, unexpected values are passed in the SaveAs dialogue box

Answer (score 0):

Upload File Using ROBOT Class

```
public String imagePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\test\\java\\filepath.pdf";

public void uploadFileWithRobot(String imagePath) {
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(imagePath);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

        Robot robot = null;

        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        robot.delay(250);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(150);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
```

Now Click on PDF and its open in new window than Verify text is present or not in PDF

```
public String readPDFInURL(String text) throws EmptyFileException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Enters into READ PDF");
        String output = "";
        URL url = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println("url :  " + url);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(fileToParse);
            output = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
            if (output.contains(text)) {
                System.out.println("Element is matched in PDF is : " + text);
                test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Element is displayed in PDF " + text);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Element is not  matched in PDF");
                test.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Element is not displayed in PDF :: " + text);
                throw new AssertionError("Element is not displayed" + text);
            }
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
            fileToParse.close();
            is.close();
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: I can be able to get the URL. To validate the URL, I passed it in a new tab without clearing any cookies. But I am unable to get the pdf there

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can download a file without using third party like AutoIT. Below is the code that works perfectly fine,

1. First you have to switch to the window.
2. Then apply some wait. So that the page will be loaded completely.
3. Now you have to trigger key events i.e. ctrl + s
4. Pop-up will be appeared on the page to save your file.
5. Just hit enter. So that you can save your file.

   ```
    String str = TestUtil.switchToWindow();
    pause(3000);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(2000);     
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);   // file replace move to yes button
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    TestUtil.switchBackToParentWindow(str);
   ```